# How to convert (key, Value) pair of Json to Proper format of Coldefs of Ag-Grid in Angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an Api which return JSON in format given below:

```
{
 Name_One:"Name One", 
 Surname_One:"Surname One", 
 Address_One:"Address One",
}
```

and in-order to insert this json in Coldefs with this code:

```
params.api.setColumnDefs(dataValue);
```

I have to convert it into format:

```
 dataValue=
 [
   {headerName: 'Name One', field: 'Name_One'},
   {headerName: 'Surname One', field: 'Surname_One'},
   {headerName: 'Address One', field: 'Address_One'},
 ]
```

So which way can I convert JSON into format given above ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include *any* attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what *you* want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

first of all your json is wrong, I fixed it from [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

**new JSON**

```
{
   "Name_One":"Name One",
   "Surname_One":"Surname One",
   "Address_One":"Address One"
}
```

create a class file

```
export class MyModel1{
Name_One: string;
Surname_One: string;
Address_One: string;
}
```

create another class file

```
export class MyModel2{
headerName: string;
field: string;
}
```

**then import both in you component**

```
import MyModel1 from './../..' //import from where you wrote it
import MyModel2 from './../..' //import from where you wrote it
```

then declare vars for this type

```
mdl1 : MyModel1[]
mdl2 : MyModel2[]
```

then save your first json to mdl1

```
mdl = jsonData // do this where you subscribe from api json
```

then push the first 2 colums in a loop to 2nd model array

```
for (let x of mdl1){

let newMdl2 = new MyModel2();
newMdl2.headerName = x.Name_One;
newMdl2.field= x.Surname_One;
mdl2.push(newMdl2);

}
```

Now **mdl2** is you desired Result